# Query working in SQL but not in MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, webgrid

i am executing a Store procedure from MVC controller, i am sending dates to it , on basis of that it sends records but problem is that When i SEND 2 dates like FROM.....TO then it sends correct result, but when i send only FROM date then it shows nothing and when i send TO date then it shows records for all employee life but not that specific date,
I executed and tested SP in SQL SERVER and there it worked correctly in every way but from MVC controller it doesn't, i don't know what is problem.

CODE:

```
public ActionResult ShowMyAtdByDate(String DateFrom, String DateTo) 
        {
            int empId = 0;
            int.TryParse((string)Session["Employee"], out empId); // parse variable to int and saves the result in empId
            IEnumerable<GetMyAtd_DateResult> MyAtdRecord = DataContext.GetMyAtd_Date(DateFrom,DateTo,empId).ToList();

            if (empId > 0)
            {
                return View(MyAtdRecord);
            }

            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("IsAuth_Page", "Home");
            }


        }
```

VIEW:

```
<div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("ShowMyAtdByDate", "Home", FormMethod.Get)) 
{
  <label id="lblFrom">From</label>
  <input type="text" class="TxtBoxFrom" name="DateFrom" />
  <label id="lblTo">To</label>
  <input type="text" class="TxtBoxTo" name="DateTo"  />
  <br />
  <br />
  <button type="submit" id="btnSubmitDate" name="btnSubmit">Submit</button>  
}
</div>

@{

     var grid = new WebGrid(ViewData.Model, rowsPerPage: 20);

  }

 <div id="AllMyAtd_ByDate">
   @grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(
                                        grid.Column("EmplID", "Employee ID"),
                                        grid.Column("EmplName","Employee Name"),
                                        grid.Column("ShiftID", "Shift ID"),
                                        grid.Column("DateVisited", "Date of Visit"),
                                        grid.Column("InTime", "In Time"),
                                        grid.Column("TimeOut", "Time Out"),
                                        grid.Column("OverTime", "Over Time"),
                                        grid.Column("TotalWorkingTime", "Total Working Time")    
                                      ))
 </div>
```

QUERY: It works with every value and shows desired result in SQL but not in asp.net MVC,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetMyAtd_Date 
@DateVisited_From CHAR(10) = NULL, @DateVisited_To CHAR(10) = NULL, @EmplID int = Null
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --If Block Beings
    IF (@DateVisited_From IS NOT NULL AND @DateVisited_To IS NOT NULL AND @EmplID IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        WITH times
        AS (
            SELECT t1.EmplID, t3.EmplName, min(t1.RecTime) AS InTime, max(t2.RecTime) AS [TimeOut], t4.ShiftId AS ShiftID, t4.StAtdTime AS ShStartTime, t4.EndAtdTime AS ShEndTime, cast(min(t1.RecTime) AS DATETIME) AS InTimeSub, cast(max(t2.RecTime) AS DATETIME) AS TimeOutSub, t1.RecDate AS [DateVisited]
            FROM AtdRecord t1
            INNER JOIN AtdRecord t2
                ON t1.EmplID = t2.EmplID AND t1.RecDate = t2.RecDate AND t1.RecTime < t2.RecTime
            INNER JOIN HrEmployee t3
                ON t3.EmplID = t1.EmplID
            INNER JOIN AtdShiftSect t4
                ON t3.ShiftId = t4.ShiftId
            GROUP BY t1.EmplID, t3.EmplName, t1.RecDate, t4.ShiftId, t4.StAtdTime, t4.EndAtdTime
            )
        SELECT EmplID, EmplName, ShiftId AS ShiftID, InTime, [TimeOut], convert(CHAR(5), cast([TimeOutSub] - InTimeSub AS TIME), 108) TotalWorkingTime, [DateVisited], CONVERT(CHAR(5), CASE 
                    WHEN CAST([TimeOutSub] AS DATETIME) >= ShEndTime AND ShiftID = 'S002'
                        THEN LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms, CAST(ShEndTime AS DATETIME), CAST([TimeOutSub] AS DATETIME)), 0), 108), 5)
                    WHEN CAST([TimeOutSub] AS DATETIME) >= ShEndTime AND ShiftID = 'S001'
                        THEN LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms, CAST(ShEndTime AS DATETIME), CAST([TimeOutSub] AS DATETIME)), 0), 108), 5)
                    ELSE '00:00'
                    END, 108) AS OverTime
        FROM times 
        Where EmplID=@EmplID AND DateVisited Between @DateVisited_From AND @DateVisited_To
        ORDER BY DateVisited, EmplID, ShiftID
    END
            --If Block Ends
    ELSE
    --Else if block begins
    IF (@DateVisited_From IS NOT NULL AND @DateVisited_To IS NULL AND @EmplID IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        WITH times
        AS (
            SELECT t1.EmplID, t3.EmplName, min(t1.RecTime) AS InTime, max(t2.RecTime) AS [TimeOut], t4.ShiftId AS ShiftID, t4.StAtdTime AS ShStartTime, t4.EndAtdTime AS ShEndTime, cast(min(t1.RecTime) AS DATETIME) AS InTimeSub, cast(max(t2.RecTime) AS DATETIME) AS TimeOutSub, t1.RecDate AS [DateVisited]
            FROM AtdRecord t1
            INNER JOIN AtdRecord t2
                ON t1.EmplID = t2.EmplID AND t1.RecDate = t2.RecDate AND t1.RecTime < t2.RecTime
            INNER JOIN HrEmployee t3
                ON t3.EmplID = t1.EmplID
            INNER JOIN AtdShiftSect t4
                ON t3.ShiftId = t4.ShiftId
            GROUP BY t1.EmplID, t3.EmplName, t1.RecDate, t4.ShiftId, t4.StAtdTime, t4.EndAtdTime
            )
        SELECT EmplID, EmplName, ShiftId AS ShiftID, InTime, [TimeOut], convert(CHAR(5), cast([TimeOutSub] - InTimeSub AS TIME), 108) TotalWorkingTime, [DateVisited], CONVERT(CHAR(5), CASE 
                    WHEN CAST([TimeOutSub] AS DATETIME) >= ShEndTime AND ShiftID = 'S002'
                        THEN LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms, CAST(ShEndTime AS DATETIME), CAST([TimeOutSub] AS DATETIME)), 0), 108), 5)
                    WHEN CAST([TimeOutSub] AS DATETIME) >= ShEndTime AND ShiftID = 'S001'
                        THEN LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms, CAST(ShEndTime AS DATETIME), CAST([TimeOutSub] AS DATETIME)), 0), 108), 5)
                    ELSE '00:00'
                    END, 108) AS OverTime
        FROM times
        WHERE EmplID=@EmplID AND DateVisited = @DateVisited_From
        ORDER BY EmplID, ShiftID, DateVisited
    END
            --Else if block ends
    ELSE
    --2nd Else if begins 
    IF (@DateVisited_From IS NULL AND @DateVisited_To IS NOT NULL AND @EmplID IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        WITH times
        AS (
            SELECT t1.EmplID, t3.EmplName, min(t1.RecTime) AS InTime, max(t2.RecTime) AS [TimeOut], t4.ShiftId AS ShiftID, t4.StAtdTime AS ShStartTime, t4.EndAtdTime AS ShEndTime, cast(min(t1.RecTime) AS DATETIME) AS InTimeSub, cast(max(t2.RecTime) AS DATETIME) AS TimeOutSub, t1.RecDate AS [DateVisited]
            FROM AtdRecord t1
            INNER JOIN AtdRecord t2
                ON t1.EmplID = t2.EmplID AND t1.RecDate = t2.RecDate AND t1.RecTime < t2.RecTime
            INNER JOIN HrEmployee t3
                ON t3.EmplID = t1.EmplID
            INNER JOIN AtdShiftSect t4
                ON t3.ShiftId = t4.ShiftId
            GROUP BY t1.EmplID, t3.EmplName, t1.RecDate, t4.ShiftId, t4.StAtdTime, t4.EndAtdTime
            )
        SELECT EmplID, EmplName, ShiftId AS ShiftID, InTime, [TimeOut], convert(CHAR(5), cast([TimeOutSub] - InTimeSub AS TIME), 108) TotalWorkingTime, [DateVisited], CONVERT(CHAR(5), CASE 
                    WHEN CAST([TimeOutSub] AS DATETIME) >= ShEndTime AND ShiftID = 'S002'
                        THEN LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms, CAST(ShEndTime AS DATETIME), CAST([TimeOutSub] AS DATETIME)), 0), 108), 5)
                    WHEN CAST([TimeOutSub] AS DATETIME) >= ShEndTime AND ShiftID = 'S001'
                        THEN LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms, CAST(ShEndTime AS DATETIME), CAST([TimeOutSub] AS DATETIME)), 0), 108), 5)
                    ELSE '00:00'
                    END, 108) AS OverTime
        FROM times
        WHERE EmplID=@EmplID AND DateVisited = @DateVisited_To
        ORDER BY EmplID, ShiftID, DateVisited
    END
            --2nd Else if ends
    ELSE if (@DateVisited_From IS NULL AND @DateVisited_To IS NULL AND @EmplID IS NOT NULL OR @EmplID IS NULL)
        --Last else begins
          Print 'No EmplID provided'
        --Last else ends    
END
GO
```

Comment: Use SQL-Profiler to look into the concrete values that are sent to the SQL Server. I guess this will give you a hint. Maybe they have not the value you expect.

Comment: i think asp.net is sending " " instead of NULL